# Reference Error Variable not declared

Tags: javascript

I've been scratching my head for hours trying to figure this out. But hours later,still no luck. So I've created a function but when I run the code it says im getting a Reference error and saying that the variable isnt declared

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src = "fileLoading.js"></script>
<script>

function initialLoad(boolean vraiFaux){
fileLoading("inventory.xml", vraiFaux); //boolean to variable
}

//function pageWrite(){
// code here
//}

</script>

</head>

<button type = "button" onClick = "initialLoad(false)">
<img  src = "panda4.png" alt="Does this work?"></img>
</button>

<body id = "body" onload="initialLoad(true)">

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my .js file

```
var xmlDoc;

function fileLoading(dname, vraiFaux)
{

if(vraiFaux){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
}


var products = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCT");
var saleItems = new Array();
var p = 0; 

for(var i = 0; i<products.length; i++){
if((products[i].getAttribute("sale")).equals("yes"){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML+=
('<img src = ' + products[i].getElementsByTagName("PIC")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</img>' ); // need spacing

saleItems[p] = i;
 p++;
if (p == 3)
break;
}

}
} 




function pageWrite(){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=
('<table border = '1'>');
var checker = 0;
for(int externalForLoop = 0; externalForLoop < products.length){


if(checker => products.length)
break;
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('<tr>');
for (int i = 0; i =< 2; i++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('<td><b><img src = ' + products[checker].getElementsByTagName("PIC")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</img></b></br></td>' + &nbsp);

} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>');
//next for loop goes after here
for (int n = 0; n =< 2; n++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
products[checker].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</b></br></td>' + &nbsp);
} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>);
//next for loop goes after here
for (int c = 0; c =< 2; c++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
products[checker].getElementsByTagName("CATAGORY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</b></br></td>' + &nbsp);
} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>);
//next for loop goes after here
for (int o = 0; o =< 2; o++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
products[checker].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</b></br></td>' + &nbsp);
} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>);
//next for loop goes after here
for (int d = 0; d =< 2; d++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
products[checker].getElementsByTagName("DESCRIPTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</b></br></td>' + &nbsp);
} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>);
//next for loop goes after here
for (int p = 0; p =< 2; p++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
products[checker].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</img></b></br></td>' + &nbsp);
} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>);
//next for loop goes after here
for (int s = 0; s =< 2; s++){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
products[checker].getElementsByTagName("SALE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</b></br></td>' + &nbsp);
} 
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</tr></br>);
//next for loop goes after here
checker++;
if (checker == (products.length - 1)){
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 
('</table>')
}

var products=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODUCT");

}
```

Comment: what's in `fileLoading.js`?

Comment: also, why is your `<button>` element outside the `<body>` tag?

Comment: my guess is that it can't find your `fileLoading.js` file... have you checked to see if that's successfully being fetched?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess it's the `boolean`. Try removing it.

In Javascript, you don't need to specify a variable's type. So, it probably reads `boolean` as a variable name, but sees that there is no variable named `boolean`, so throws a reference error.

Additionally, `fileLoading.js` contains multiple syntax errors. I'd recommend looking at the errors it should be producing for you…

In particular:

- Line 26 is missing a right paren
- Bad quotes on line 44
- Unexpected `int` on line 46 (don't need those!)
- Line 46 needs a 3rd clause in the for-loop
- Used `=>` instead of presumably `>=` on line 49
- Unexpected `int` on line 53
- Used `=<` instead of presumably `<=` on line 53
- `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity, not a Javascript variable; move into the string on line 55
- And even more; I'm going to bed now, but you should be able to find the rest with your console's help.

This is one of the reasons that I recommend building software in small pieces and testing between each piece: debugging a huge chunk of code like this is seriously painful, and many of these errors wouldn't even exist if you'd caught their first instances early.

Comment: Tried it, but still gives me the same error. The error is now fileLoding is not defined. Before it was initialLoad is not defined

Comment: It's not that you don't need to. It's an error to do that in JS. Variables don't have type. Objects do.

Comment: ill post my js file as well

Comment: I can't be sure if all browsers throw that error... I would hope so. Chrome certainly does.

Comment: @user2444526, @Hristo: Oops, deleted a comment since it was wrong-ish, but here's the post-mortem: so it looks like the syntax error in the inline script caused `initialLoad` never to be defined, throwing a reference error. The new reference error probably means that your `fileLoading.js` either is not loading properly (404?) or doesn't define the `fileLoading` function.